# sound_play change language

Tags: ros, sound-play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to change the language of sound_play. Since it is based on festival, I have downloaded the relative language package and setted it as default for festival. In festival it works, but sound_play still speaks in its default english.
How can I change the default sound_play language?
Is it also possible to change language when sound_play node is running?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48297/sound_play-change-language/) by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 620 on 2012-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the solution. The method "say" in sound_play.h takes a voice as argument and if it is omitted, the default is the English one.

---

Originally posted by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) with karma: 620 on 2012-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0